# Wordpress get fullurl from user_meta img

Tags: arrays, wordpress, templates

I have a user image upload (from Paid Memberships Pro Register Helper) which I want to place in a template file. If I do:

```
<?php 
  $key = 'logo'; 
  $single = true; 
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  if(!empty($user_last)){
    var_dump($user_last); }
  ?>
```

I get:

```
 array (size=7)
  'original_filename' => string 'jp-logo.png' (length=11)
  'filename' => string 'jp-logo.png' (length=11)
  'fullpath' => string '/rel-local-path/jp-logo.png' (length=111)
  'fullurl' => string '/full-local-path/jp-logo.png' (length=87)
  'size' => int 20869
  'previewpath' => string '/rel-thumbnail-path/jp-logo-200x168.png' (length=119)
  'previewurl' => string 'full-thumbnail-path/jp-logo-200x168.png' (length=95)
```

from this, how do I `echo` the `'fullurl'` value on the page?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
echo $user_last['fullurl'];
```